# EZBounce Make error

Tags: makefile, debian

I am trying to install ezbounce on an SSH Shell. (Host has OK'ed use of the bouncer)
(I do NOT have sudo, however, my host is lenient and I can get things ran. If possible, I prefer a solution that does NOT require sudo or equivalent.)

I have finished `./configure` , and am on the `make` step.

when I go to make the file, it errors with the following:
https://pastebin.com/YetM6nGN

I found a possible solution to the problem here:
https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=219298
The solution seems to be centered on the fact that GCC++/GNU make calls its latest version as opposed to the newer one.

They have an included patch, but I am honestly clueless how this gets applied.

Any help fixing the error via here or directly editing the makefile is greatly appreciated.

My makefile: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u75toiigd4v5wgl/Makefile?dl=0

Comment: Note, for the patch, I tried adding that line they added in the patch viewable here:https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=184746&action=diff#Makefile_sec1

Still no luck, so I undid my changes to keep the file clean

Answer (score 0):

So I had some help from an external source (Thank you discord communities!)

The patch listed above is for FreeBSD ONLY! (As I was made aware)

For Non-FreeBSD Ports, the fix (if your makefile looks like mine) is to edit line 32 to the following: `CXX_OPTIMIZATIONS = -std=gnu++98 -O2`

There is some error looking items in console that follows, but the build is successful, so I'm gonna assume they are moot.

It honestly was a confusing little puzzle for your average user, but there ya go :)